# Highlighting text on type: irregular function behavior

Tags: python, tkinter

I have two text windows. When the user types `/` the line this is on should highlight in yellow. This should happen for both windows. The bug I have is typing `/` in the left window does not highlight the line *until* a line with `/` is also typed in the right window. Then the program works as it should. I'm confused because the identical function is called.
Here is the minimal code:

```
#! python3
from tkinter import *

def search(text_widget):
    pos = '1.0'
    while True:
        idx = text_widget.search('/', pos, END)
        if not idx:
            break
        idx = idx.split('.')[0]     # start of line
        pos = '{}.0'.format(int(idx) + 1)   # end of line
        text_widget.tag_add('steno', '{}.0'.format(idx), '{}.end'.format(idx))

def changeText(*args):
    if '/' in Left_Text.get(1.0, END):
        search(Left_Text)

    if '/' in Right_Text.get(1.0, END):
        search(Right_Text)

    else:
        Left_Text.tag_remove('steno', 1.0, END)
        Right_Text.tag_remove('steno', 1.0, END)



root = Tk()

frame = Frame(root)
Left_Text = Text(frame, width=20, height=20)
Left_Text.tag_configure('steno', background='yellow', foreground='black')
Left_Text.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)
Left_Text.bind("<Key>", changeText)

Right_Text = Text(frame, width=20, height=20)
Right_Text.tag_configure('steno', background='yellow', foreground='black')
Right_Text.pack(side=RIGHT, padx=5, pady=5)
Right_Text.bind("<Key>", changeText)

frame.pack()

mainloop()
```

Comment: In `changeText`, change the 2nd `if` to an `elif`. Or better yet, give each `if` its own `else`.

Answer (score 1):

If you type something with a "/" in the left, you first hit this statement:

```
if '/' in Left_Text.get(1.0, END):
    print("searching left...")
    search(Left_Text)
```

That will add the highlighting just as you wish.

Next, you have the following code. Because the condition is false, you fall through to the else:

```
if '/' in Right_Text.get(1.0, END):
    print("searching right...")
    search(Right_Text)

else:
    Left_Text.tag_remove('steno', 1.0, END)
    Right_Text.tag_remove('steno', 1.0, END)
```

Thus, you are adding the highlighting and then immediately removing the highlighting.

You should change your logic to be (notice the use of `elif` in the second condition):

```
if '/' in Left_Text.get(1.0, END):
    ...
elif '/' in Right_Text.get(1.0, END):
    ...
else:
    ...
```

By the way: the first index of the widget is `"1.0"`, not `1.0`. The indexes are strings, not floating point numbers. Floating point numbers work in some cases, but only by a side effect of the implementation. You should get in the habit of always using strings for indices.